Self-inverse elements in quotient of fundamental group
I am researching some stuff in Topology at the moment and I am kind of stuck and lack ideas, as I am also quite new to this field. My issue is the following:
I am given a finite graph (or $1$-complex) X and a normal subgroup $H$ of $\pi_1(X)$. Now I have some result that is applicable if the quotient $\pi_1(X)/H$ has no element of order 2. So I am wondering what I can infer on either $X$ or $H$ if the opposite is true, i.e. if I assume that there exists som $g\in \pi_1(X)/H$ with $g\neq 1$ such that $g^2=1$.
So far I am super lost and don't quite know if there is even some interesting direction to pursue. It is a well-know fact that $\pi_1(X)$ is free, but I don't see how that helps.
I'd appreciate any ideas or materials that might touch this subject.
Thank you in advance!

It's not clear to me what would constitute an answer to this question. $\pi_1(X)$ is a free group, so it has many quotients, some of which have elements of order $2$. Are you looking for examples? Non-examples?

Good question :D. Ultimately I am looking for something structural for $X$, in the sense that this cannot happen if $X$ has some property. That however seems a bit out of reach. Right now I am trying to understand the problem a bit better. So both examples and non-examples would help or anything that is known about such quotients.

There's no hope of phrasing a condition in terms of $X$ only (other than the trivial one that $X$ is a tree so that $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial); you need a condition in terms of $H$ also. But it's unclear what to say here because you just said $H$ is an arbitrary normal subgroup. Some normal subgroups have quotients with elements of order $2$ and some don't, there's not really much to say about this without more information about what you're looking for.

Normal subgroups of free groups are absurdly general; if $\pi_1(X)$ is free on $n$ generators then its quotients include every group that can be generated by $n$ generators. And, for example, already for $n = 2$ this includes every finite simple group (this is not at all obvious and is a corollary of the classification).

I see. The subgroup $H$ is not arbitrary but non-trivial and I cannot yet say anything structural about it. So I was hoping that maybe since $X$ is a nice topological space this restricts some of the weirdness that can happen. But as I said this is a big shot in the dark :D
I appreciate the feedback!
